# How to Find the centre of a circle, using two points on the circumference.

Tags: circles

I'm trying to find the equation of a circle, which I can easily work out if I knew the centre of it. However, the only information I'm given are two points on the circle that form a chord and an image that shows a rough placement of the circle on the grid.
[Image of the Circle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpooR.png)
I was given this question by my teacher, so if no one can help me, I will go back to her to see if there is a solution.

Thanks for any help,
Alex.

Comment: The picture suggests that the circle is tangent to the $x$ axis. That means you do have enough information to find its center. Is that enough help for you?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248374/calculate-circle-given-two-points-and-conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$CA = CB$, so $C$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $[AB]$, which is given by $x = 2$, so $x_C = 2$. Now, clearly, $D(2,0)$ is a point on the circle. Hence, the center lies on the perpendicular bisector of $[BD]$, which you can find its equation. Substituting the coordinates of $C$ in that equation you get $y_C$.

Comment: Thank you I just realised that as I posted this question and I came out with an answer of (x-2)^2 + (y- 16/3)^2 = 100/9 , for the equation of the circle, however, feel free to say if you got a different answer. Thanks for the help though.