# Calculate circle given two points and conditions

Tags: geometry, circles

there are a lot of ways to calculate a circle given two points given the formula $(x-k)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$ on this board. However these are not unique as there are arbitrary many possibilities to draw a circle through two points (with different radius).

I want to add another condition, such that there is only one possible solution. My condition is that one point is the highest point. To sketch my problem, I created an image with R.

[image: Circle]

As you can see in this specific image, the center is given for $p_0=(0,0)$ (`blue dot`, generally unknown), the highest point is given for $p_1=(x_1,y_1)$ (`green dot`, highest value, known) and another point $p_2=(x_2,y_2)$ (`red dot`, known value) is given as well. The `red` and `green lines` have the length of the desired radius $r$ (unknown) and the `gray line` is known through points $p_1$ and $p_2$.

So to sum up, I know the two values $p_1$ and $p_2$ and I'm searching for the radius $r$. I thought that the `gray line` might give me some information utilizing an equal-sided triangle, but so far I had no luck.

So my question is: How can I calculate radius $r$ given two points $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247984/how-to-find-the-centre-of-a-circle-using-two-points-on-the-circumference

Comment: @EthanBolker: It might be related, but I would argue you that the question asked on that thread falls under the first part of my description that I excluded. It can be solved by the formula (also first part), but consider the following in that question: That $C$ is in the center of $AB$ (also valid) and comparing the resulting circle with the given the picture it is not a unique circle anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t$ be the angle between the green and the grey line. The length of the grey line is $|p_1p_2|=2r\cos t$.

Using the given coordinates for $p_1$ and $ p_2$ we also have $|p_1p_2|\cos t=(y_1-y_2)$.

We can now solve for $r$ finding $$r={1\over 2}{ |p_1p_2|^2\over (y_1-y_2)}$$ and the coordinates for the centre are $$C=(x_1,y_1-r)$$

Comment: I implemented your equation into my algorithm in R and works nicely. Thank you!

Comment: Happy It helped.

Answer (score 1):

The highest point is directly above the center.  The center has to be on the perpendicular bisector of the segment $p_1p_2$ (all points equidistant from $p_1, p_2$ are on the perpendicular bisector, and the center is exactly $r$ away from both).

So the center is the intersection of a vertical line through the highest point and the perpendicular bisector of the segment $p_1p_2$.  Then $r$ is easy to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

The highest point lies directly above the center of the circle.  So if the center is an unknown $(x,y) $ then the highest point is $(x,y+r)=(x_1,y_1) =p_1$.  Or $x=x_1;y=y_1-r $.

So if $p_2=(x_2,y_2) $ then $r=\sqrt {(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1+r)^2} $.

Solving we get: 
...

====== old answer =======

If $(x,y)$ is the "highest" point then the tangent line to that circle is horizontal and the center of the circle is $(x,y-r) $ (ie the center of the circle lies "directly" below $(x,y) $ a distance of $r$ lower.)

So given the other point is $(u,v) $ we need to solve that $(u-x)^2+(v-y+r)^2= r^2$. (i.e the distance from $(u,v) $ to $(x,y-r) $ is $r$.

===

So $(u-x)^2+(v-y)^2+2r (u-y)+r^2=r^2$

So $r=\frac { (u-x)^2+(v-y)^2 }{2 (y-u)}$

Comment: In the old answer, $(u-y)$ should be $(v-y)$

Comment: Hey fleablood, your and N74 answers are both right and yours is very nice and detailed! I marked N74 as correct answer, because he answered first and implementing his solution was very fast. However I want to explicitly thank you for describing the steps in detail.